# Stream video located outside the root

Tags: php, video-streaming, mp4

before i get burried in trying to create the code, I was hoping to get some advice before moving forward.

I am creating a video sharing app for a client.

The videos are highly confidential, so i want to store them outside the root and stream them when a user enters a link into a browser, which triggers a php script to access the file and play it.

Is this possible?

I can seem to find any info on any forums or Google.

Can I stream it direct to the browser?

I had this working when the files were inside the root.

I am holding the url of the file in a var:

```
$file_url = "../users/$u_id/$folder_name/$file_name";
```

And trying to stream the video using html5 player video.js using this:

```
    <div id="video_box">
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
controls preload="auto" width="500" height="350"
poster="images/img_name.png"
data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
<source src="$file_url" type='$file_type' />
</video>
</div>
```

Many thanks

Alan

Comment: `fpassthru` http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php you will also need to set access restrictions via a login or users can still download the file.  Your best bet if you are inexperienced with this is to use a 3rd party service.

Comment: Yes its possible, as long as php can access the file, but if you want seeking, fpassthru is **not** the way to go. You would need to create a script that will accept and handle `$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']` headers. also you will need to get familiar with, uploading large files, converting them with ffmpeg, getting screens of the video with ffmpeg.

Comment: Edited content above so you can see how im trying to do this.

Comment: How did you resolve this?